# Regex - Find all matching words that don't begin with a specific prefix

Tags: regex

How would I construct a regular expression to find all words that end in a string but don't begin with a string?

e.g. Find all words that end in 'friend' that don't start with the word 'girl' in the following sentence:

"A **boyfriend** and *girlfriend* gained a **friend** when they asked to **befriend** them"

The items in **bold** should match. The word *'girlfriend'* should not.

Comment: For regex questions, it is helpful to mention what language you are working in because there can be differences in regex syntax for the same task.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could try:

```
\b             # word boundary - matches start of word
(?!girl)       # negative lookahead for literal 'girl'
\w*            # zero or more letters, numbers, or underscores
friend         # literal 'friend'
\b             # word boundary - matches end of word
```

**Update**

Here's another non-obvious approach which should work in any modern implementation of regular expressions:

Assuming you wish to extract a pattern which appears within multiple contexts but you only want to match if it appears in a specific context, you can use an alteration where you first specify what you don't want and then capture what you do.

So, using your example, to extract all of the words that either are or end in `friend` except `girlfriend`, you'd use:

```
\b               # word boundary
(?:              # start of non-capture group 
  girlfriend     # literal (note 1)
|                # alternation
  (              # start of capture group #1 (note 2)
    \w*          # zero or more word chars [a-zA-Z_]
    friend       # literal 
  )              # end of capture group #1
)                # end of non-capture group
\b
```

Notes:

1. This is what we **do not** wish to capture.
2. And this is what we **do** wish to capture.

Which can be described as:

- for all words
- first, match 'girlfriend' and do not capture (discard)
- then match any word that is or ends in 'friend' and capture it

In Javascript:

```
const target = 'A boyfriend and girlfriend gained a friend when they asked to befriend them';

const pattern = /\b(?:girlfriend|(\w*friend))\b/g;

let result = [];
let arr;

while((arr=pattern.exec(target)) !== null){
  if(arr[1]) {
    result.push(arr[1]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

which, when run, will print:

```
[ 'boyfriend', 'friend', 'befriend' ]
```

Comment: Note that while many flavors of regular expressions do not support look-behind, most do support look-ahead. The answer I gave will work in JavaScript, which does not support look-behind.

Comment: Although not the quickest answer, +1 for the explanation! Small nitpick though: `\b` is better called a "word boundary".

Comment: @BartKiers, true but in this instance it serves the purpose of delimiting the start and end of the word.

Comment: sure, I know. But the fact that your first called it "start" and then the 2nd one "end" might lead one to believe they match different things on different places. Also, a "boundary" is the (IMO) better word here since it is then clear that it is a "zero-width" pattern (it matches no character, just a position). But, like I said: a small nitpick.

Comment: I took the liberty to create an example of this in regex101 https://regex101.com/r/cE0dM7/1

Comment: @ArneHB, it's usually polite to provide attribution when one copies another's work.

Comment: @RobRaisch You are aware that regex101 is just a online regex tester to show how your regex works? It's just an addition to your answer for people to verify that it works. Also considered it's a comment on your answer and also "example of this" implies that it's your regex.

Answer (score 10):

This may work:

`\w*(?<!girl)friend`

you could also try

`\w*(?<!girl)friend\w*` if you wanted to match words like `befriended` or `boyfriends`.

I'm not sure if `?<!` is available in all regex versions, but this expression worked in Expersso (which I believe is .NET).

Comment: That will always match "friend" (and an empty string inside group 1)

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Where does it always match? It doesn't match "girlfriend" when I test in Expresso.

Comment: Correct, it does not match the word "friend" with the word "girl" in front of it. What I meant is that in case of the word "boyfriend", only the word "friend" is matched. This is what it will always match: just the word "friend".

Comment: The OP stated: _"The items in bold should match."_ which are "boyfriend", "friend" and "befriend" ("boy" and "be" included). But, there's no real reason to adjust your answer, IMO, since the correct answer has already been posted more than once.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
/\b(?!girl)\w*friend\b/ig
```

Comment: Can you please explain the notation?

Comment: It is pretty well explained in the accepted answer by Rob Raisch

Answer (score 4):

I changed Rob Raisch's answer to a regexp that finds words Containing a specific substring, but not also containing a different specific substring

```
\b(?![\w_]*Unwanted[\w_]*)[\w_]*Desired[\w_]*\b
```

So for example \b(?![\w_]***mon**[\w_]*)[\w_]***day**[\w_]*\b will find every word with "day" (eg day , tuesday , daywalker )  in it, except if it also contains "mon" (eg monday)

Maybe useful for someone.

Comment: It does not seem to work with non alphanumeric chars. For example if i want to retrieve all dots "." except in the words starting with "@". (ex: Hello. @some.thing is not working . --> should detect dot after "Hello" and at the end of the sentence but not in "@some.thing").

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to exclude some words that have a given prefix from regex matching result

the text was query-string params

```
?=&sysNew=false&sysStart=true&sysOffset=4&Question=1
```

the prefix is `sys` and I dont the words that have sys in them

the key to solve the issue was with word boundary `\b`

```
\b(?!sys)\w+\b
```

then I added that part in the bigger regex for query-string

```
(\b(?!sys)\w+\b)=(\w+)
```