# Regex to match specific strings without a given prefix

Tags: regex

I need to match all of its lines that contains a value and that don't have a given prefix.

Example:
I want all lines that contains `word` when it's not prefixed by `prefix`

So:

```
foobar -> no match
prefix word -> no match
prefix word suffix -> no match
word -> MATCH
something word -> MATCH
```

What I've tried so far:

```
(?!prefix)word
```

Doesn't seem to do what I want

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308334/regex-find-all-matching-words-that-dont-begin-with-a-specific-prefix/71006839#71006839

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You may need

```
(?<!prefix )word
```

(and maybe take care of the spaces).

`(?!)` is a negative lookahead but in your case you need a negative lookbehind (i.e. `(?<!)`).

Comment: This will incorrectly match the line "prefix another word" . The question specified that the line started with prefix and contained "word" but didn't say "word" always immediately followed "prefix".

Comment: This solution is not supported in some browsers and earlier versions of Node. Is there an alternative?