# How do I match PATTERN but not PREFIX_PATTERN?

Tags: regex, grep

Say I've got some documents that contain several lines with `KEYWORD` and some lines with `PREFIX_KEYWORD`.

How would I match only these lines that have `KEYWORD` and ignore the lines that have `PREFIX_KEYWORD` on them?

Yes, I could grep for `KEYWORD`, feed the results into the editor of my choice and let the editor delete all lines that have `PREFIX_KEYWORD` but I'm asking whether there's a built-in way in grep to do this.

If this helps: I'm not interested in the exact match but only want to know whether there are occurrences of `KEYWORD` in the file.

Comment: Have you considered `grep KEYWORD | grep -v ^PREFIX_KEYWORD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to grep for your KEYWORD and filter out the rest. This could look like

```
grep KEYWORD file | grep -v PREFIX_KEYWORD
```

Another way with a perl expression:

```
grep -P '(?<!PREFIX_)KEYWORD' file
```

The same answer was given here: [Regex to match specific strings without a given prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781561/regex-to-match-specific-strings-without-a-given-prefix)

Comment: didn't know the `-v` switch. Works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -w KEYWORD your_file
```

man page for `-w` says:

```
 -w    Searches for the expression as a word as if surrounded
       by \< and \>.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the word `KEYWORD` by itself, why not regex for `KEYWORD` with any special character before (space, newline, etc.)?