# how to match a pattern avoiding a prefix?

Tags: pattern-matching, pcre, prefix

I am trying to match a pattern but AVOID a prefix -- negative look behind is not working (due to greediness of remaining pattern?) -- help would be appreciated!

Example:

```
(?<=procedure\()\s*(?<!ada)\w+\(
```

was expected to match:
procedure( **add_test(**

but NOT:
procedure( ada_make(

NOTE: the following post on stackoverflow is NOT helping, as KEYWORD in my case is not a literal (and /w+ is getting greedy!):
[How to match a pattern but not prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334841/how-do-i-match-pattern-but-not-prefix-pattern)[How do I match PATTERN but not PREFIX_PATTERN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334841/how-do-i-match-pattern-but-not-prefix-pattern)

Here is a link to regex101 showing a match: [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/iW7hU1/1)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second lookbehind, you can use lookahead instead:

```
(?<=procedure\()\s*(?!ada)\w+\(
```

Answer (score 0):

problem found: if using negative look behind (as stated) one should remove/not use the global modifier (default: g)
if removed, the above Regular Expression does the job -- apologies; see better answer: using negative look ahead instead too