# Regular expression for match sentences not starts with specified prefix

Tags: regex, c++builder-xe

I would like to find strings in double quotes but only if they used outside of call of specified function `foo`. For example:

```
foo("some str1"); // ignore
foo2("another string"); // need this
"simple string"; // need this
foo(L"wide str"); // ignore
#define NAME "name" // need this
int i = foo("must be ignored"); // ignore
```

I have tried `\b(?!foo\()L?"[^"]*"\b` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308451/3240681), but it doesn't work correct. Used end double quote on one line as begin on another. Like this `"); // ignore<CR> foo2("`

If I suppose I should include possessive quantification. To substring not satisfying excluded completely from further search. But don't know how to do it correctly.

It is required to search for files in the Embarcadero RAD Studio XE, but satisfied with any decision in the Perl regexp syntax.

**Important**: wants to find all occurences of double quoted strings outside of `foo` function. And not to be distracted by a string inside the `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/mG7gP7/1
I match two scenario

- Search for function not name foo, and match the string inside quotes.
- Any text inside quotes where there is no function call

Comment: Good one. Is it possible to modify expression to satisfy second quoted word in the last line [link](https://regex101.com/r/qC9eB7/1)?

Comment: Hum... sorry no, I won't play the game of refactoring for every uses cases you create.

Comment: If your version of the code is found to occurrence of a string with quotes, not all line completely, my clarifying questions would not arise. I unfortunately could not describe every possible option in example. The main thing to understand of the matter is the need to find **all occurrences** regardless of their possible count in one line of text. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah I get what you want, @ryuichiro answer does the job.

Comment: not exactly. I added **important** block to my question.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this [one](https://regex101.com/r/vQ3gE6/1)?

```
/(^(?!foo\()|\)).*"(.*)"/gm
```