# Regex - Find biggest possible match, which would have been found without preceding word checking, or nothing

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I do not know the exact terminology and therefore could unfortunately not find a solution for my particular case.

I know how to find a single word, which is not proceeded by another predefined word using negative lookahead.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308334/regex-find-all-matching-words-that-that-dont-begin-with-a-specific-prefix)

My goal is to match only the biggest possible phrase, which would be matched without the added check for a preceding word. If they are following a comma, I do not want any of the matches in that group. If no comma ahead, I want all of them in one phrase.

My basic idea would be to do the normal regex and the check again if there is a comma in front of the match. Can it be done in one pass, though?

Example (stupid one):
The House **566 819** , 94841 681 , is nice **4571 68484 81981**

Ideal output:

- 566 819
- 4571 68484 81981

I want all numbers to be matched, which do not directly follow a comma (desired matches are bold), as one big match.

My current regex for this case looks like this:

\b(?!,)\s((\d+\s*)+)

It however also finds 681 because it is a number and no comma is in front.
This is an unwanted behavior to me.

I hope I explained my problem well enough.
Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What language do you use? Note that `(?!,)\s` is redundant since a whitespace isn't a comma.

Comment: Your pattern isn't working as described. `94841` is not matched because of the `\b` not because of the lookbehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex

```
(?<=[^,\d]\s|^)(\d+(?:\d+\s*)+)
```

Will match the longest number and whitespace combo directly preceded by `^` (beginning of line) or anything but `[,\d]\s` (a comma or a digit followed by a whitespace).

Is this what you where looking for? I had a hard time understanding your question so I went based on:

> I want all numbers to be matched, which do not directly follow a comma

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much. I guess the "trick" here was to not allow any digit in front (The [^,\d]), right?

Comment: yes, we want regex to always group together all numbers, meaning that there should never be any numbers preceding it.

Note also that there is no word boundary in my regex either as it adds too much limitation.