# Regex - Find matching words that don't begin with a specific prefix in IntelliJ IDEA'a Find in path

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'd like to find any occurrence of specific word which is not preceded by other specific word using IntelliJ IDEA's Find in path (ctrl+shift+f).
For example I'd like to find "end" but not "front-end".

There is similar question:
[Regex - Find all matching words that that don't begin with a specific prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308334/regex-find-all-matching-words-that-that-dont-begin-with-a-specific-prefix)
but solutions from there doesn't work in IntelliJ IDEA.

Do you know any way how to do it in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Are your "words" separated with spaces? Try `(?<!\S)(?!front)\S*end(?!\S)`. The problem here is with word delimiting approach. Usually, words consist of letters, digits or `_`. In your example, `-` is not a word char.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, it works! (Words are separated with "-") Write your comment as an answer so I could mark it as a solution if you want.

Comment: If it works, words are separated with whitespaces in your case.

Comment: Let's consider 4 cases: 1."front" 2."front-end" 3."front end" 4."end". Your solution passed 3 and 4. Case number 2 was filtered so this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Sure, words are whitespace separated entities here.

Comment: `end(?<!front-end)`

Comment: Thank you sln, your solution works for me too

Comment: sln don't you want to write it as answer? I think it could be valuable for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with word delimiting approach. Usually, words consist of letters, digits or `_`. In your example, `-` is not a word char.

Since your words are whitespace separated you may use

```
(?<!\S)(?!front)\S*end(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](http://(?%3C!%5CS)(?!front)%5CS*end(?!%5CS)).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string should appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!front)`  - no `front` can appear immediately to the right of the current location
- `\S*` - 0 or more chars other than whitespace
- `end` - `end` substring
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string should appear immediately to the right of the current location.